# Is anyway to dynamic add static image resource at react-native app

Tags: react-native

I have a project using react-native. When ready to upgrade the js bundle file, I come across a problem: In this upgrading, I need add some image resouce, so I have to copy the dest file to the src/main/res/ folder and regenerate the project. It's seem not so 'dynamically'.The second way is encoding the image resource using base64; it's work but ugly，especially there are lots of images. Certainly I could use network Images as react-native document describes, but it's 'expensively'. So is another way that loading new static images and  needn't regenerate the project?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Image source={require('./intro.png')} />
```

You can require images just like you require js files.
In the above example intro.png would be in the same folder as the js file.

Hope that helps